# How to reuse this little block of code in React.js?

Tags: react-router, reactjs

I'm a total react Newb, but here is the code I have:

```
var ExampleComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {close: false};
  },
  handleClick: function(event) {
    this.setState({close: !this.state.close});
  },
});

  var ButtonThing = React.createClass({
   <ExampleComponent />,
   render: function() {
    <div> yo </div>
    );
  }
 });
```

Where the "ExampleComponent" can be used in multiple places? I've tried what I have above and just putting in "ExampleComponent" straight, but no luck. Or am I just going about this wrong?

Comment: Also take a look at [react-stamp](https://github.com/stampit-org/react-stamp) for a much more sophisticated and powerful (yet easy to use) alternative.

Comment: You shouldn't use mixins btw. Use higher-order components instead. [Read this.](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.v7may2yya)

Comment: Louy - how would that look using the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code reuse in react is facilitated by a concept called mixins.

The [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins) give a concise example.

For your case

```
var exampleMixin = {
  getInitialState: function() {
   return {close: false};
  },
  handleClick: function(event) {
    this.setState({close: !this.state.close});
  }
}
var ButtonThing = React.createClass({
  mixins: [exampleMixin], // Use the mixin
  render: function() {
    return (<div> yo </div> );
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `React.createClass` you can try use [`mixins`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#mixins), like this

```
var ComponentStateMixin = {
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { close: false };
  },

  handleClick: function(event) {
    this.setState({ close: !this.state.close });
  }
};

var ButtonThing = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ ComponentStateMixin ],
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={ this.handleClick }>Close</button>
      <p>{ 'ButtonThing state:: ' + this.state.close }</p>
    </div>;
  }
});

var Modal = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ ComponentStateMixin ],
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={ this.handleClick }>Close Modal</button>
      <p>{ ' Modal state:: ' + this.state.close }</p>
    </div>;
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26826/)